# Selecting element in SCSS by referencing multiple parents on the same line

Tags: html, css, sass

**UPDATE:**
*It was a typo. I wrote ".ltem" instead of ".item". The code below is correct.*

Assuming that in out project we have only one stylesheet for those two pages underneath:

Example of an HTML page:

```
<div class="container-first">
    ...
    <div class="item"> </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Example of another HTML page:

```
<div class="container-second">
    ...
    <div class="item"> </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I know one can select an element (.item) in SCSS by using a parent node reference like this:

```
.item {
    .container-first & {
        background: black
    }
    .container-second & {
        background: black
    }
}
```

But how can we reference multiple parent nodes for the same child element on the same line?

I did this but it's not working:

```
.item {
    .container-first &, .container-second & {
        background: black
    }
}
```

And I couldn't find anything enlightening on the internet.

In other words, how can I do to select the ".item" element by referencing multiple parents on the same line **inside** the ".item"'s curly brackets?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on Codepen/JSfiddle/something? I don't see a reason why your code wouldn't work. Even tried it here: https://codepen.io/helb/pen/PJKXMQ

Comment: I'm voting to close; the question has little value since no one else can reproduce it, and you can't seem to explain what caused the compile error.

Comment: I've investigated further and actually I had a typo in a class name that was causing a wrong selecting ".ltem" instead of ".item". Sorry for that! We can close it if you think it's better to. @Blazemonger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work.

The following SCSS

```
.item {
    .container-first &, .container-second & {
        background: black
    }
}
```

compiles to:

```
.container-first .item, .container-second .item {
      background: black;
}
```

Try it in the [online sass playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/9e2bf1ada47b7707149d50e84e7d1d6e).

Comment: It was a compiling issue in my project, you guys are right. Sorry for wasting your time.

What do you think should I delete the thread or leave it? (I think it can be helpful for somebody else)

Comment: No harm in leaving it.